# .NET MVC lookup using modal postback to form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to do a Membership Lookup in a Modal and if a result is found upon clicking a button the Member's Address is posted back to the current form.

Would anyone have any examples of how to do the postback to the appropriate form fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to achieve this supposing you're searching for the user's name:

In the popup retrieve the matched member info with an AJAX get request and place the returned data inside a `<span id="address">` for example.

When clicking the button in the popup, use jQuery to retrieve this `<span>` value and insert it inside the corresponding `<input id="user-address"/>`

```
$("#user-address").val($("#address").val());
```

As you see, there's no need to postback anything to the `<form>`. You already have the data in the popup. It's just a matter of copying this data to the corresponding `<form>` input fields.

Comment: Ok but I have Address1, Address2, Addres3, Town, County, Postcode, Country. Would the same principle apply?

Comment: Sure... the same principle. Just add each piece of data inside their corresponding `<span>`s and then copy their info to their corresponding `<input>`s in the form.

Answer (score 0):

the modal would have it's own `<form>` and would post to a specific action.

this action will do the look-up and return the view that you were previously on

Comment: Yeah that bit is fine. My query is how do I populate the appropriate address fields with the posted data.